Restore matplotlib navigation toolbar option
On updating my computer, I lost my favorite button in Matplotlib.
Here's the new configuration:

and here's the old configuration:

The old configuration has that zigzag button (the penultimate one, between the sliders and the floppy) while the new configuration does not. The zigzag button pulled up options to change xlim/xscale//ylim/yscale, and I used it all the time.
How can I restore this button to use?
I've tried finding its name in other overflow questions, hoping to add it to backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2.toolitems, but I couldn't find it anywhere, as if it never existed!
When I try to add ("Customize", "Edit axis, curve and image parameters", "subplots", "edit_parameters") which I think may be the right one (but I'm not convinced at all; that may be the sliders), I get:
AttributeError: 'NavigationToolbar2Tk' object has no attribute 'edit_parameters'


You're using different backends: The customize button is only available for the QT backend, it uses it's own NavigationToolbar2QT toolbar instead of the standard NavigationToolbar2 toolbar and inserts the Customize button. Your new configuration looks like the TkInter backend (TkAgg).
See Backends for how to change backends.

Ah, wonderful! I hadn't manually changed the backend, so I didn't realize that could be my problem. Thanks so much for the information!
Just adding
mpl.rcParams["backend"] = "QtAgg"
solved the problem for me on one computer; with the other I had to additionally download qtagg in the first place:
sudo pacman -S python-pyqt6
Thanks for the help, Stef!

Incidentally, this also fixed my complaint about the display suddenly being woefully miniscule. Thanks again!
